# ProgressDialog not showing in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am uploading some file to server using AsyncTask and I want to show a progress dialog in AsyncTask.
My AsyncTask is working fine and executing all the steps, but it never shows the dialog.I don't know what I have done wrong.
I have written below code but not working. Can someone help please!!!

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView videoImage ;
    EditText editTextVideoTitle;
    EditText editTextVideoDescription;
    Button btnPostButton;
    Button btnCancelButton;

    private String mVideoPath;
    private String mVideoThumb;
    String strVideoTitle;
    String strVideoDescription;
    boolean videoPosted;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_vid_with_desc);

       
        editTextVideoTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.videoTitle);
        editTextVideoDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.videoDescription);

        btnPostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);
        btnCancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);;

        mVideoPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        mVideoThumb = getIntent().getStringExtra("thumb");

       
        btnPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                videoPosted = postVideo();

                if (videoPosted) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your video posted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in posting video, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
    
    public boolean postVideo() {

        Log.i("Info", "PostVidWithDescActivity : postVideo : Start");

        String strUserId = "";
        String strReservedfield = "";
        boolean isVideoPosted = false;

        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.app.rapid", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        strVideoTitle = editTextVideoTitle.getText().toString();
        strVideoDescription = editTextVideoDescription.getText().toString();
        
        
        try {

            strUserId = sharedPreferences.getString("userId", "");
            strReservedfield = "ReservedField";
        
            outputData = new PostToServerAsyncTask().execute(mVideoPath, strUserId, strVideoTitle, strVideoDescription, strReservedfield).get();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (null != outputData && outputData.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {
            isVideoPosted = true;
        } else{

            isVideoPosted = false;
        }

        

        return isVideoPosted;
    }

private class PostToServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String content;
        private String Error = null;
        private int serverResponseCode;

        Context context;

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            Log.i("inputBuilder","PostToServerAsyncTask : onPreExecute Start") ;

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            //progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            Log.i("inputBuilder","PostToServerAsyncTask : onPreExecute End") ;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... inputData) {


                /*
                    File upload code
                */

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            

            return "Some string";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.i("inputBuilder","PostToServerAsyncTask : onPostExecute Start") ;

                if (null != progressDialog && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }


            Log.i("inputBuilder","PostToServerAsyncTask : onPostExecute End") ;
        }
        
}
}
```

Comment: Please show how you call your async task.

Comment: @blackapps, Now I have posted complete activity and AsyncTask inside it, please review.

Comment: It is is because of the .get() that you dont see the progress dialog. Dont use .get(). Handle the result of doInBackground in onPostExecute.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, It worked...million thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            //progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
    });
}
```

I think the general problem is in async task, which actually is on the separate thread

Comment: @BalajiMote, After more deep investigation of the code, I've noticed that you are using `get` instead of `execute`, this makes call exactly on the UI thread and blocks it. On the other hand, `execute` will work in async mode, so you will have to make somes additions in your code to handle the response. Could you please try `execute` insted of `get`?